# How to include string fstream and iostream libraries in makefile

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, include, libraries

I need to compile and run several files but I do not know how to include standard libraries into my makefile. In this case I need to include `string`, `fstream` and `iostream` libraries. My search on the web was disappointing. I thought with either `libraryname` or with `-llibraryname` you can include them, but I was wrong. I gives me an error every time. The file to compile are written in c++. Thank you for your time.

```
# default command, builds an executable called "magasin".
# executable can be called with make magasin
all: magasin
    # link the object files into the executable.
    # the -lm option is to tell the linker to include math libraries.
    magasin: client.o panier.o produit.o rayon.o main.o
        g++ -o $@ $^ string vector iostream fstream

    # compile the Client.cpp file into the client.o object file.   
    client.o: Client.cpp Client.h                                
        g++ -o client.o -c Client.cpp string

    # compile the Produit.cpp file into produit.o object file
    produit.o: Produit.cpp Produit.h                                
        g++ -o produit.o -c Produit.cpp string

    # compile the Rayon.cpp file into the rayon.o object file.
    rayon.o: Rayon.cpp Rayon.h                                
        g++ -o rayon.o -c Rayon.cpp string vector

    # compile the Panier.cpp file into the panier.o object file.
    panier.o: Panier.cpp Panier.h
        g++ -o panier.o -c Panier.cpp string vector

    # compile the main.cpp file into the main.o object file.
    main.o: main.cpp Produit.h Rayon.h Client.h Panier.h 
        g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp string iostream fstream


# remove the executable and intermediary object files.
clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly include standard library in your compiler flags. Your C++ compiler will known to link these in automatically.

Comment: Do you know "how to include standard libraries" when running the compiler from the shell prompt? It's done exactly the same way from a makefile.

Comment: I am not sure how to include libraries from a shell prompt.

Comment: @Artour, Sam was being snarky. See Brian's comment.

Comment: e.g. `g++ -o client.o -c Client.cpp` should do the trick.